# Get embedded object from entity by entity id using Spring Data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, spring-data

I have an entity `Applicant` which contains `@Embedded` `Name` object (`firstName`, `lastName` etc.). I would like to get only the embedded object from database by applicant id using Spring Data.

I'm trying like this:

```
public interface ApplicantRepository extends Repository<Applicant, UUID> {
    Optional<Name> findNameById(final UUID applicantId);
}
```

but it returns the whole Applicant entity instead of just Name. Is there any option to name the function in different way to achieve this with Spring Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using Query Annotation in Spring-data.

```
    @Query("select applicant.name from Applicant applicant where applicant.id = :id")
    Optional<Name> findApplicantNameById(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks! But I'm just curious - is there any other way for this, without using `@Query` annotation? Based only on method name.